# Is there a locally compact space which is not a k-space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

**Definitions**:

> A locally compact space is a space where every point has a local base of compact neighborhoods.
>
> A $k$-space $X$ has its topology generated by maps from compact Hausdorff spaces, i.e. $C$ is closed iff for every compact Hausdorff space $K$ and every continuous function $f: K \to X$, $f^{-1}[C]$ is closed in $K$. [Strickland's notes](https://neil-strickland.staff.shef.ac.uk/courses/homotopy/cgwh.pdf) call this *compactly generated*.

By compact I mean not necessarily Hausdorff.

The reason I ask is that standard constructions of non $k$-spaces for example the square of the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{Q}$ and the product $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3}\} \times \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ where the second quotient means identifying $\mathbb{Z}$ to one point, are usually not locally compact.

I'm looking for a locally compact space which is not a $k$-space.

Comment: Do you know it must exist, or is it just a hunch?

Comment: Well if locally compact implies k space that would be pretty amazing

Comment: How many locally compact non-Hausdorff spaces do you know off? Cofinite is one that comes to mind but I think that it’s not a $k$-space in your sense.

Comment: The cofinite topology is sequential, thus it is a k-space

Comment: Do you know other examples?

Comment: Maybe a product of sieripinski spaces?

Comment: You'd need a large product of them, or else we'd have a first countable hence sequential non-example. Say $\mathfrak{c}$ many at least..

Comment: I think this doesn't ever work unfortunately

Answer (score 4):

The answer is that, assuming AC, there are locally compact spaces which are not compactly generated. (That is, do not have topologies which are final with respect to all maps with compact Hausdorff domains. i.e. do not belong to the monocoreflective hull of the class of compact *Hausdorff* spaces as computed in $Top$.)

The construction of such a space is due to J. Isbell, *[A Distinguishing Example in k-Spaces](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1987-100-03/S0002-9939-1987-0891170-3/)*, Proc. Am. Math. Soc. **100** (1987), 593-594. Below is my attempt at his details.

Let $X=\omega_1+1$, where $\omega_1$ is the first uncountable ordinal, and topologise $X$ by giving it the base of *closed* sets generated by $(i)$ countable initial segments $[0,\alpha]$, and $(ii)$ the singleton $\{\omega\}$. The space $X$ is our counterexample.

> $X$ is locally compact.

*Proof*: Indeed, more is true: every subspace of $A\subseteq X$ is compact. For $A$, if nonempty, contains a least element, every neighbourhood of which contains all of $A$ except for possibly $\omega_1$. $\square$

> $X$ is not compactly generated.

Proof: The claim is that there is a non-closed subspace $A\subseteq X$ with the property that whenever $f:K\rightarrow X$ is a continuous function with $K$ a compact Hausdorff space, the preimage $f^{-1}(A)$ is a closed subset of $K$. We will show that the open subspace $A=[0,\omega_1)$ has this property.

So take $K$ and $f$ as above and suppose $f^{-1}[0,\omega)\subset K$ is not closed. Fix a countable ordinal $\alpha_1$ and consider the closed set $f^{-1}[0,\alpha_1]\subseteq K$. This is disjoint from the closed set $K\setminus f^{-1}[0,\omega_1)$, so by normality of $K$ there are disjoint open sets $U_1,V_1\subset K$ with $f^{-1}[0,\alpha_1]\subseteq U_1\subseteq X\setminus V_1\subseteq f^{-1}[0,\omega_1)$. Because we are assuming that $f^{-1}[0,\omega_1)$ is not closed we have $X\setminus V_1\neq f^{-1}[0,\alpha)$, so in particular the inclusion $U_1\subseteq f^{-1}[0,\omega_1)$ is proper. Thus there is a countable $\alpha_2>\alpha_1$ for which there is a proper inclusion $U_1\subseteq f^{-1}[0,\alpha_2]$.

Now iterate the process to obtain a sequence of proper inclusions
$$f^{-1}[0,\alpha_1]\subseteq U_1\subseteq f^{-1}[0,\alpha_2]\subseteq U_2\subseteq\dots$$
Since $\bigcup_\mathbb{N}\alpha_i$ is countable, $\bigcup f^{-1}[0,\alpha_i]=f^{-1}(\bigcup [0,\alpha_i])$ is closed in $K$ and hence compact. On the other hand it is covered by the $U_i$, but by no finite subfamily of them. Thus there is a contradiction. It must be that $f^{-1}[0,\omega_1)$ is closed in $K$. $\square$

*Remark*: $(i)$ All that was needed of $K$ was its compactness and normality. A more general statement from which the proof flows is contained in Isbell's paper. $(ii)$ We quietly used the axiom of choice to ensure that $\bigcup\alpha_i$ as countable.

Comment: I realize this is pretty old but in case you get a chance to look at this again, when you define your topology as generated by "countable initial segments $[0,\alpha]$ and  $\{\omega_1\}$", you have to consider ***all*** countable initial segments, not simply closed ones.  Otherwise $\bigcup [0,\alpha_i]$ need not be closed.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactly_generated_space In the example section it is said that locally compact space are $k$-space.

Comment: Yeah this is one of the problems with terminology which is why I took so long defining all the terms lol. Wikipedia defines k space differently so it's sort of obvious in their definition that it includes locally compact spaces. Whereas for me LCH is k space but without Hausdorff it's not obvious

Answer (score 0):

Surely yes. For every C$^*$-algebra $A$, the primitive ideal space $Prim(A)$ is locally compact (in the sense of each point having a neighbourhood base of compact sets) in the hull-kernel topology. But $Prim(A)$ is seldom Hausdorff.

What about the C$^*$-algebra $A$ of the bounded operators on a separable Hilbert space? Then $Prim(A)$ consists of the ideal $\{0\}$ and the ideal $K(H)$ of compact operators. Topologically it is a two-point $T_0$ space with one point open and the other point closed. Is that a $k$-space?

Comment: I think I can map an interval to the two point space so that the inverse of the open point is (0,1] and not closed. Hence it's a k-space.

Comment: That's a nice example. How about a sequence of closed points converging to two closed points at infinity? Is this a $k$-space?

Comment: so I don't think about this stuff anymore but I think any first countable topology is k-space, so probably?