# Is a locally compact weak Hausdorff space Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, examples-counterexamples, separation-axioms

##### Definitions.

Let $X$ be a topological space.  We say $X$ is

> **locally compact** if every member of $X$ has neighborhood basis of compact sets.

> **weak Hausdorff** if for every continuous map $f\colon Z\to X$, where $Z$ is compact Hausdorff, $f(Z)$ is closed in $X$.

---

##### Question.

> ($Q$) Must a locally compact weak Hausdorff space be Hausdorff?

---

##### Additional background.

This question has an equivalent formulation in terms of compactly generated spaces, or "$k$-spaces".  We need a few more definitions.

> A subset $A\subseteq X$ is **$k_2$-closed** (resp. **$k_2$-open**), if $f^{-1}(A)$ is closed (resp. open) for every continuous map $f\colon Z\to X$ from a compact Hausdorff space $Z$.

(Often the above is simply called "$k$-closed", but there are several competing definitions for that term, one of which we are about to introduce here, so we borrow the terminology from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4761129/1210477) for precision.)

> A subset $A\subseteq X$ is **$k_3$-closed** (resp. **$k_3$-open**) if its intersection $A\cap K$ with every compact Hausdorff subset $K\subseteq X$ is closed (resp. open) in $K$.

For $n=2$ or $3$, $X$ is

> **$CG_n$** ("compactly generated") if subsets in $X$ are closed if and only if they are $k_n$-closed.

> **$k_n$-Hausdorff** if the diagonal in $X\times X$ is $k_n$-closed.

The last definition really isn't especially interesting for $n=3$ in light of the answers [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4762527/1210477)  Also there is a definition for $k_1$ as well; it won't be relevant for us, but see the preceding links.

---

##### Equivalent and related questions.

As discussed in the first link above, under either $CG_n$ assumption, the weak Hausdorff condition is equivalent to the otherwise stronger condition $KC$ (Compact subsets are closed).  However, the $KC$ condition in turn immediately upgrades to $T_2$ in the presence of local compactness, as we obtain a basis of closed neighborhoods at each point, which combines with $T_1$ to yield $T_2$.  (We get $T_1$ from the weak Hausdorff condition, as every singleton is the image of a compact Hausdorff space, hence closed.)

Conversely, any locally compact Hausdorff space is easily seen to be $CG_n$  for either $n$.

As a result, the following question, for either $n=2$ or $3$, is equivalent to ($Q$).

> ($Q_n$) Must a locally compact weak Hausdorff space be $CG_n$?

Finally, we note that in general, weak Hausdorff implies $k_2$-Hausdorff, and under either $CG_n$ assumption, the two are equivalent.

Therefore, we could also ask

> ($Q'$) Must a locally compact $k_2$-Hausdorff space be Hausdorff?

> ($Q_n'$) Must a locally compact $k_2$-Hausdorff space be $CG_n$?

An affirmative answer to either of these equivalent (to each other) questions implies an affirmative answer to the other questions.

In general, a big part of what motivated this question was my desire to find more examples of spaces that are $k_2$-Hausdorff or even weak-Hausdorff, yet fail to be $KC$.  As explained above, in the locally compact case any non-Hausdorff example will also fail $KC$, leading me to this line of inquiry.

---

##### Addendum.

Regarding ($Q_n$), I had difficulty finding any example at all of a locally compact space that failed to be a $CG_2$-space. [$\pi$-base turned up nothing](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=locally+compact+%2B%7ECG2), though [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3904987/1210477) did give a nice non-$T_1$ example.
(The original paper referenced there explains how to modify the example to be $T_1$, but after such modification it will still fail to have any reasonable separation, as it will not even have unique limits for convergent sequences ($US$), so will not answer our questions here.)

For locally compact spaces that fail to be $CG_3$, $\pi$-base [only has non-$T_1$ examples.](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=locally+compact+%2B%7ECG3+%2B%7ET1)

Comment: Still another equivalent question would be: Does locally compact + WH imply regular?

Comment: pi-base is missing a few simpler results with the KC assumption as you mentioned: (1) weakly locally compact + KC ==> locally relatively compact; (2) locally compact + KC ==> $T_2$.  We can at least add those if no answers to this question become available.